# Problem with regularization : "float has no dtype"

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need some help because I cannot use regularization in tensorflow. I installed-it today, and I am new on this. Here is my code :

```
 def buildmodel(dim,neurons_on_layers,X,Y,ep,batch):
     le=len(neurons_on_layers)
     ne=neurons_on_layers
     model = Sequential()
     model.add(Dense(ne[0], input_dim=dim, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0),
                activity_regularizer=regularizers.l1(0)
                activation='relu'))  #change from 'relu'  
     for j in list(range(1,le)):
          model.add(Dense(ne[j],  
                   activation='relu'))    ##changed from 'relu'  'tan'
          model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
          model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy']) ##normal
          model.fit(X, Y, epochs=ep, batch_size=batch)
    return model
```

When I compile it, it returns :

```
 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

into the "_handle_activity_regularization" function.

And when I remove the regularizations, the code works (but without regularization, my algorithm learn nothing). Does anyone know a trick in order to make penalties into my code ?

Thanks,

Comment: Its probably expecting a numpy array. Try ```X = np.array(X)```

Comment: Nothing happen.

Comment: can you post the whole error and what X and Y are?

Comment: I added in the following !